# Twitter Lists not getting rendered in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter, frontend

I have tried rendering the twitter list of a profile, but its showing

Twitter list pic

[image]

```
<div className="centerContent ">
    <div className="selfCenter standardWidth">
        <div style={{ marginTop: "-4.2rem" }}>
            <a
                className="twitter-timeline"
                data-dnt="true"
                href="https://twitter.com/SportziInfo/lists/bcci-11202?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw?s=20"
            >
                A Twitter List by SportziInfo
            </a>
```

Can you please suggest a way to handle this list? I want to embed in my website

I have tried with TwitterTimelineEmbed component but its not working

Answer (score 0):

What problem you got with TwitterTimelineEmbed ??
I guest that is problem of Twitter https://twittercommunity.com/t/again-list-widget-says-nothing-to-see-here-yet-if-logged-out/198782/247

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem. TwitterTimelineEmbed didn't able to show list timeline